# Open source or Paid Search Engine API

Tags: php, mysql, solr, full-text-search, search-engine

I have a MySQL database with two main tables that contain the data I need to index. I am looking for a search engine API that can index and return appropriate search results - as close as possible to Google quality -. The application uses the keywords and creates pages based on the search results.

I have tried SOLR but am not sure if that is the best one. Any other paid or open source alternatives you may have come across? The project is LAMP based.

Thanks,
Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr/Lucene are definitely the de-facto when it comes to open source search World. I love Solr. No! you dont need to go for anything "Paid" :). In my opinion (if you want to go for something else) you try out [Sphinx Search Engine](http://sphinxsearch.com/), its absolutely amazing, integrates extremely well with LAMP. Infact the PHP API that ships with it is really good and you can get started with Search using Sphinx in almost no time.